# CSS - Clip-path doesn't work well on safari

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, css-shapes

I'm developing a menu with shape but in safari it doesn't work well.
In safari it damage the layout and i don't know why.
If i do not use svg tag and use just css clip-path it work well in safari and chrome but not in firefox.

Css:

```
   .menu {
  width: 65%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(5% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(5% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 100%);
  -webkit-clip-path: url("#clipping");
  clip-path: url("#clipping");
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
}

.menu:before {
  content: '';
  width: 99.8%;
  height: 40px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(5% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(5% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 100%);
  -webkit-clip-path: url("#clipping");
  clip-path: url("#clipping");
  background: black;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  right: 2px;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="menu">
 <svg width='0' height='0'>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipping" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
     <polygon points="0.05 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 1" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
 </svg>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Partial support refers to supporting shapes and the url(#foo) syntax for inline SVG, but not shapes in external SVGs. http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path

Comment: so, how can i do that? @Rob

Comment: In 2020, clip-path in Safari (13.1) is still buggy and slow. At least it is now supported without prefix.

Answer (score -2):

clip-path css property is not supported by safari (webkit) and most of ie, edge versions.

Comment: so, what is the solution? @VolkanSağ

Comment: Why do you want to clip div? you can draw any design with svg path that you want.

Comment: If you want to clip, you should create a div with css-> overflow: hidden; position: relative; and inside this, you should create a div position: absolute; and left and top that you want:)

Answer (score -2):

It is working for me in safari

```
 <svg viewBox="0 0 250 250">
  <polygon points="125,30 125,30 125,30 31.9,63.2 46.1,186.3 125,230 125,230 125,230 203.9,186.3 218.1,63.2" />
  <polygon points="125,30 125,52.2 125,52.1 125,153.4 125,153.4 125,230 125,230 203.9,186.3 218.1,63.2 125,30" />
  <path d="M125,52.1L66.8,182.6h0h21.7h0l11.7-29.2h49.4l11.7,29.2h0h21.7h0L125,52.1L125,52.1L125,52.1L125,52.1
      L125,52.1z M142,135.4H108l17-40.9L142,135.4z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: if i get out the css clip-path: url() it works fine in safari but doesn't work in firefox. @AbdullahKanza